# how to calculate significance across several conditions

Tags: r, statistics

my data looks like this

```
df<- structure(list(Accession = c("AAAAA", "MYDDD", "STDTTT"), First_Rep1 = c(24.8432602, 
33.36984063, 30.93297676), First_Rep2 = c(25.16806123, 33.59779257, 
31.71292828), Condition1_Rep1 = c(28.74214021, 36.89735285, 35.67871257
), Condition1_Rep2 = c(28.68311263, 37.12617154, 35.89283737), 
    Condition2_Rep1 = c(28.60045356, 36.85154916, 35.3600596), 
    Condition2_Rep2 = c(27.5609252, 36.25666317, 34.87004551)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

what I wish to do is to calculate p value across each condition for each Accession.

when I want to do it one by one, I do it like this

```
t.test(mydf[1,2:3],mydf[1,4:5])$p.value
```

so I take the values for the first accession (row1) then first condition included First_rep1 and First_rep2 versus the condition1_rep1 and condition1_rep2

Is there a better way to calculate p values for all possible combination of each Accession (just each row)

here is my old data

```
df<- structure(list(Accession = c("AAAAA", "AAAAA", "MYDDD", "MYDDD", 
"STDTTT", "STDTTT"), grp = c("Rep1", "Rep2", "Rep1", "Rep2", 
"Rep1", "Rep2"), First = c(24.8432602, 25.16806123, 33.36984063, 
33.59779257, 30.93297676, 31.71292828), Condition1 = c(28.74214021, 
28.68311263, 36.89735285, 37.12617154, 35.67871257, 35.89283737
), Condition2 = c(28.60045356, 27.5609252, 36.85154916, 36.25666317, 
35.3600596, 34.87004551)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

output looks like this

```
Accession  First_Condition1_pvalue First_Condition2_pvalue   condition1_condition2_pvalue
1 AAAAA     0.0234                  0.08346332               0.4377075              
2 MYDDD     0.00209                 0.03711208                0.3463036
3 STDTTT    0.0416                  0.02344368                0.1838468
```

Comment: This is what is referred to as the [`xy problem`](https://xyproblem.info/). You previously asked to reformat the data, now you are asking to do t.test. Notice that you could have asked to do t.test  instead of data formating. Now we have to format it back to how it was before just to run a t.test

Comment: The best way to go about this is to use the data in its original form. ie before you pivot it into wider format

Comment: you remember the data you wanted us to reshape? Use that data and do a groupby and compute the t.test on each group

Comment: @onyambu
 I put the old data here in the post

Comment: So why did you have to reshape it if your interest was the p-value and not the pivoted data?

Comment: @onyambu
because I need to do it for all conditions and not only 1 or 2 that is why it is hard for me to solve it

Comment: Include your expected output and it will be easily solved for you

Comment: @onyambu
I added it above

Comment: @nick check the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
   pivot_longer(!1:2)%>%
   group_by(Accession)%>%
   reframe(pairwise.t.test(value, name,'none',FALSE)$p.value%>%
             as.data.frame.table(responseName = 'value')) %>% 
   drop_na() %>%
   pivot_wider(id_cols = Accession, names_from = c(Var1, Var2))

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  Accession Condition2_Condition1 First_Condition1 First_Condition2
  <chr>                     <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
1 AAAAA                     0.438          0.0234            0.0835
2 MYDDD                     0.346          0.00209           0.0371
3 STDTTT                    0.184          0.0416            0.0234
```

Comment: thanks but the p value is calculated over which one versus which one? it should be First (rep1,2) versus condition 1(rep1,2) , then first(rep1,2)versus condition2(rep1,2) then condition 1(rep1,2) versus condition 2 (rep 1,2) for each accession